# Running pod setup gives me "bad interpreter: No such file or directory" error

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods, podspec

Recently I tried to do `pod setup` and I get this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I followed Ray Wenderlich's guide to install CocoaPods and I get this issue so I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Ruby installation incorrect?

Comment: What is your system? [Darwin (Mac OS X)?] How did you install Ruby? [brew? ports? from source?] How are you managing Ruby versions? [RVM? rbenv?] Which guide by Ray Wenderlich did you follow? [there are several]

Comment: The error basically tells you that the interpreter you are attempting to use is not there. 
Look at the /usr/local/bin/pod, first line (one that starts with #!) and you should see the ruby interpreter there. 

Is there anything in /usr/local/opt/ruby? 
Are you using rbenv, rvm?

Comment: @Mircea, do you know what that file is for?

Comment: Mine shows version 2.3 in usr/local/binpod file but I believe I have Ruby 2.6. So getting similar error. Do you know a clean way to update this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i fixed it by running `brew install ruby`

Comment: I had to reinstall `rew uninstall cocoapods` `rew install cocoapods` after I installed ruby to make the error go away.

Answer (score 514):

I encountered this problem when upgrading to Mac OS High Sierra.

This was my fix:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I found this answer on [the CocoaPods issue list on Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6778).

Comment: This one fixed it for me.

Comment: don't forget sudo: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: I had the same issue and doing a `brew update` and `brew upgrade` installed the latest cocoapods for me and did the trick

Comment: Downvoted because of the use of sudo. See various answers on StackExchange for installing ruby/gems without it. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414249/how-to-install-gems-without-sudo-on-mac-os-x

Comment: This also has fixed it for me, Plus one for the great answer, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: If this doesn't help, try **restarting** Terminal.

Comment: This helps with Catalina too.

Comment: This fixed it for me on macOS Catalina. Thank you :)

Comment: I didn't think it will help but it did, macOS Catalina.

Comment: Ugh! You should never use sudo to install gems. I wrote a detailed, top-rated answer for safely installing gems on a Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191

Answer (score 128):

This happened when I upgraded to Catalina.
I solved it by running:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin ruby
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: This was the solution for me after upgrading to Catalina.

Comment: You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

Comment: Along with this I also had an issue with openssl that I had to fix first - `brew uninstall openssl & brew install openssl`

Answer (score 77):

After upgraded to High Sierra, I got the same error, just reinstalled the cocoapods

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: Worked well, nice!

Comment: This is needed for High Sierra. Thank you.

Comment: For those who updated to Catalina, this is needed as well.

Answer (score 54):

Same issue I was facing when I updated our system from `Sierra` to `Mojave.` Also works for Catalina

The following steps worked:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

I got the help from the following [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6898#issuecomment-333230288).

Comment: Getting the same issue after upgrading to Catalina. This helps! Use `Sudo` in front to get write permission fwiw.

Comment: I ended up here after Catalina installation. This works well.

Comment: worked for me after updating 10.14 Mojave to 10.15 Catalina

Answer (score 23):

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

[This line saved my day.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6898#issuecomment-364133270)

Comment: Eventually this fixed the issue for me

Comment: Also saved my day!

Answer (score 15):

The following worked for me:

> Select Command Line Tools in XCode.
>
> ```
>     XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > XCode 11.X.X
>
> In terminal execute:
>
>     sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60464653

Answer (score 7):

After upgrading from OS X Mojave to OS X Catalina I received this message when running `pod init` or `pod --version`:
`-bash: /Users/mangolassi/.gem/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I don't like the idea of `sudo gem install cocoapods` so I have my .cocoapods folder in my user directory and I've modified my .bash_profile to point to it.  The error I received was because the version 2.3 was hard coded in this file:
`/Users/eric/.gem/bin/pod` and Catalina came with 2.6.

It's possible that using sudo install would overwrite this file successfully, and probably does, but I wanted to keep my original setup.

I was able to to just modify the first shebang line of the file `/Users/eric/.gem/bin/pod` to have a path with 2.6 instead of 2.3 and it worked.  The entire change was changing the '3' to a '6' in my chase as the version was still '2'.

Comment: Nice! Only this answer worked for me. Apparently after upgrading to Catalina ruby 2.3 was replaced with 2.6

Answer (score 6):

While I'm trying to install again then I got another error saying that

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

Then I did this and worked fine.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Most likely you didn't need to uninstall. That error just says you don't have the correct permissions to do what you were trying to do. So adding `sudo` was all you needed. See the comment from [https://stackoverflow.com/users/877341/blackhawk4152] above

Answer (score 6):

On my mac this solved the problem:

```
brew uninstall cocoapods

brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 5):

### for MACOS X Catalina

Tried most of the answers but none worked. If the above doesn't work try Opening Xcode preferences > Locations > selecting Command Line Tools to Xcode. Then install cocoapods

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 5):

The error in the original post is due to an improperly configured Ruby environment. You [should never use `sudo` to install gems](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/?utm_source=stackoverflow), no matter how many times you see it as an accepted answer on Stack Overflow.

At a high level, setting up a proper Ruby development environment on a Mac involves six steps:

1. Install Homebrew (which also installs the prerequisite Apple command line tools)
2. Install a Ruby manager (such as chruby, rbenv, asdf, RVM) - most of these can be installed with Homebrew
3. Configure the Ruby manager by adding the appropriate lines to your shell file (`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`) - each manager will have instructions for doing this, and this is a typical step that people miss
4. Restart the terminal (or open a new tab) for the shell changes to take effect - another step that is often overlooked
5. Install a specific version of Ruby using the Ruby manager
6. Switch to that version of Ruby using the Ruby manager

My personal preference is [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). For a step-by-step guide, check out my [detailed tutorial for setting up Ruby on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/).

Answer (score 4):

I came across a similar issue when I tried upgrading the cocoa pods version using:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

To fix this, cocopaods had to be linked with xcodeproj using the command below:

```
brew link cocoapods
```

If the linking fails, then you should be able to link by overwriting the previously existing link as follows:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

The "rubyist approved" way of doing this is to install a ruby version manager (rbenv) and install cocoapods through that. Messing with `sudo` and your rubygems is going to lead to tears.

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing of the above worked. I had ruby 2.3.0 installed and I had to downgrade to 2.0.0:

`gem update --system 2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Find the pod file. Mine was located at usr/local/bin/pod

You'll find that the top line says version 2.3. Edit this file to the correct version number. Save a copy of the original incase you mess it up.

Try your pod related commands again.

Worked for me after days of trying everything.

Answer (score 0):

vi pod
then replace the ruby path 2.3 one to the path which u get by using
which ruby command in terminal
then do pod setup it will work
this worked for me after trying all the listed solutions .

Answer (score 0):

re-installing ruby solving issues on my case (error happen after I  upgrade Mac OS to Monterey). it's take a bit of time to reinstall but it worked

Answer (score 0):

Technically Symlink to Ruby is broken.

Fix it by executing command: `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/<version> /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby`

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Many users have described methods similar to solve the problem.

Comment: Mostly others are suggesting to reinstall ruby or cocoapods. Both are installed correctly. Its only symlink issue. I do not find any such answer.