# cocoapods permission issue in High Sierra?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods, macos-high-sierra

I updated my macOS to High Sierra, Now installing dependencies through cocoapods in my iOS application. But I face the following error.

```
XXXXXXXXX:MyProject CompanyName$ pod update 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Than i tried

```
 Zubair-mac-mini:~ sdsol$ gem install cocoapods

 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
Zubair-mac-mini:~ sdsol$
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442214/running-pod-set-up-gives-me-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution after a lot of search.

1: Update your terminal to the latest version.

2: Download and Update RubyGems to the latest version from: https://rubygems.org/pages/download

3: Thin I update my pod file. through pod update.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem after upgrading to macOS High Sierra and got it fixed with following commands (note, you need to use `sudo` to run as super user):

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin
```

Good luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: yup same here, first command fails for the same reason and second one worked, thank you

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to macOS High Sierra, get it fixed with following commands:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

`eval "$(rbenv init -)"` 
to `~/.bash_profile` file

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: would you please express how this fixes the issue?