# This terminal won't let me run or install cocoa pods because I am on MacOS Catalina Beta?

Tags: cocoapods

I am interested in installing one of the GitHub repos that requires installing CocoaPods. There is no problem with my terminal (seems fine in a normal macOS version). I have one problem though: terminal is not installing CocoaPods, seemingly because I'm on the macOS Catalina beta?

I did install the pod 'Card' from `Podfile` which finished but after that `Podfile` closes. I am going running "pod install" on the terminal, then the only error that I get is:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: / 
System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory".
```

Does someone know how to fix this issue for macOS Catalina?

Comment: Ruby is present in Catalina, but I don't know what version it is, and in future versions it won't be present at all. You can use a ruby version manager and install 2.3 yourself if that's the issue. Also did you use `sudo`? It might help, I don't know.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

worked for me

Comment: This did not worked for me, i have run to multiple answers on the web but i still have the same error:ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
 invalid gem: package metadata is missing in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/cache/httpclient-2.8.3.gem

Comment: Please make sure u di not forget this line: 
XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > XCode 11.X.X

Comment: this won't work until you have new Xcode 11. then it will work

Answer (score 47):

Use

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
```

The Mojave bottle is linked to a different version of Ruby. The --build-from-source option will link the cocoapods gem to the Catalina version of Ruby.

Comment: I had to follow this up with `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks! This answer + this comment saved my day.

Comment: This was the only way to install cocoapods on Catalina for me. All other answers failed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: fantastic, tried several commands to reconfigure the broken cocoapods. `brew install cocoapods --build-from-source` and `brew link --overwrite cocoapods` were the only ones that worked, thanks

Answer (score 21):

I also encountered this issue when I upgraded to Catalina and XCode 11. Here's what I did to fix this:

1. Select Command Line Tools in XCode.

> *XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > XCode 11.X.X*

2. In terminal execute:

> *sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin*

Comment: Perfect! Seems so obvious, to set the xcode command line tools path, but I really haven't thought of this myself... Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. My macOS is Catalina 10.15.4.

Answer (score 10):

Try this to get `cocopods` works on `macOS Catalina`

```
$ brew cleanup -d -v    
$ brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by installing cocoa pod again.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 5):

I had not been able to solve use this one

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Before this command I ran the following command and reinstalled cocoapod.

```
xcode-select --install
```

.

This worked for me

```
 xcode-select --install
 sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Catalina, to solve I have to made the following steps:

1. Install XCode Command Line Tools, I recommend install the HomeBrew to solve that dependency: 
   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Execute this command to reinstall cocoa pods: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

```
    [![If cannot install new version cocoapods, example below:
    1. Please remove Command line tools
    sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
    2. Install new Command line tools version
    sudo xcode-select --install
    3. after installing run below command
    open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, worked for me

1. Go to Xcode preferences -> Locations 'tab'.
2. Check the Command Line Tools section. If it's blank, make sure your current command line tools is selected.
   XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > XCode 11.X.X
3. Run `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

So, issue is that in Mac OSX Catalina. The folder path `/usr/local/bin` is private.

So,
Step 1: Install Homebrew. "Homebrew lets your access private folders and enables them to public".

Step 2: Restart Terminal or restart Mac OSX.

Step 3: Run `sudo gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Step 4: Let the setup complete

Step 5: Run pod setup

Finished :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install cocoapods using brew

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
```

if u have already installed cocoapods using brew it will not let you install cocoapods
then try

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

then write

```
pod setup --verbose
```

hope it will work.