# Flutter Issues with MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: flutter, dart, macos-catalina

After updating to **MacOS 10.15 Catalina**, there are problems with **Flutter**.

Specifically, Flutter doctor complaints about the following:

**Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.**

**CocoaPods not installed.**

It is important to explain that before updating, when my computer was running *Mojave 10.14*, these *issues with Flutter did not exist*, thus flutter doctor -v reported no issues whatsoever.

Regarding the first issue: **Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.**

Flutter doctor offers this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207

Nevertheless, the linked article refers to *Linux*, not *MacOS*...

Regarding the second issue: **CocoaPods not installed.**

Flutter doctor suggests the following solution:

**brew install cocoapods**

**pod setup**

Nevertheless, although *"install cocoapods"* works fine, *"pod setup"* fails, indicating the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/pod: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.7.4/libexec/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pod: line 2: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.7.4/libexec/bin/pod: Undefined error: 0
```

Running **flutter doctor -v** offers the following result:

```
[!] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.8.1, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A501i, locale es-PA)
    • Flutter version 1.8.1 at /Users/podriasereltuyo/flutter
    • Framework revision d3eee57c0b (7 days ago), 2019-07-08 11:04:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 3c51a7bfff
    • Dart version 2.5.0 (build 2.5.0-dev.0.0 b5aeaa6796)
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information



[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
MacBook-Air-de-Podria:ptyce podriasereltuyo$ flutter doctor -v
[!] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.8.1, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A501i, locale es-PA)
    • Flutter version 1.8.1 at /Users/podriasereltuyo/flutter
    • Framework revision d3eee57c0b (7 days ago), 2019-07-08 11:04:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 3c51a7bfff
    • Dart version 2.5.0 (build 2.5.0-dev.0.0 b5aeaa6796)
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information



[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/podriasereltuyo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        brew install cocoapods
        pod setup

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 37.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I humbly wish to ask for your help, please, to clarify what does it mean when it says **Downloaded executables cannot execute on host**?

and, what may be done to resolve it? **Please?**

also,
if cocoapods was running beautifully when using Mojave 10.14, what may be the issue now, being seemingly unable to successfully run **pod setup**?

is anyone else here having **any issues with Flutter** after upgrading to **MacOs 10.15** Catalina Beta, which *you were not having before with Mojave*?

### THANK YOU !!!

Update...
Researching about this issue, I've encountered a very sad comment, which suggests that basically there is no support for Flutter in Catalina...

Please find it here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34000

The comment says:
**Flutter is not yet supported on macOS 10.15**, although we're obviously looking at it. This is a duplicate of #22598, which relates to the removal of 32-bit support from Catalina.

*So, I am beginning to think that it might be a good idea to go back to Mojave's safety, at least Flutter was working fine...*

**Please share your thoughts, suggestions, advise?**

Answer (score 12):

Its possible to install cocoapods, run flutter build ios and run on the iOS simulator.

- `brew uninstall cocoapods`
- `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`
- `pod install`

Detailed instructions are here: [This terminal won't let me run or install cocoa pods because I am on MacOS Catalina Beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572116/this-terminal-wont-let-me-run-or-install-cocoa-pods-because-i-am-on-macos-catal)

Comment: thank you immensely !!!

indeed, the problem regarding CocoaPods indeed has now been resolved !!!

Comment: Flutter Doctor now says: Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.4

Comment: nevertheless, the other issue still remains, which says:
**Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.**

Do you have any idea how may this other issue be resolved?

THANK YOU !!!

Comment: Upgrading from Mojave to Catalina, this fixed my flutter build issues. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

For this issue:

> [!] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.7.11, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A487m, locale
>   en-SE) ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host. See
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information

Easy fix:
Open a terminal on MAC and run the following commands:

```
> flutter channel master

> flutter doctor
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall and install it again (fe if you are using `homebrew`).

Just run:

```
brew uninstall cocoapods && brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

For issue like :-

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information.
```

CocoaPods is an open-source dependency manager for Xcode projects. When you develop a mobile app for iOS, you can use CocoaPods to define all of your dependencies in a simple text file, called a Podfile

just do :-

```
brew install cocoapods
```