# Flutter `Device doesn't support wireless sync` error on macOS Catalina

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, macos-catalina

After updating macOS to Catalina, Flutter project can't Build\Run and indicates this error:

[image]

1. I tried to 'run' the project via xCode and it worked properly, but with AndroidStudio can't run the application
2. on Android device project works fine
3. Flutter (Channel beta, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.15)
4. Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)

Answer (score 2):

Flutter updated to (Channel beta, v1.10.7, on Mac OS X 10.15) and the problem was resolved, But then maybe the following issues occurs:

### 1- Build error

[image]

If you encounter this error just update `cocoapods`:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

This answer: [Flutter Issues with MacOS 10.15 Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050554/flutter-issues-with-macos-10-15-catalina#answer-57064205)

---

### 2- Stuck at `Installing and launching` on iOS device

1. Change flutter channel to master in Terminal

   ```
   flutter channel master
   ```
2. ```
    flutter upgrade
   ```
3. (In my case) It was necessary to build and execute the project once

Comment: This did the trick. After the upgradation to catalina studio stopped detection of ios devices. I've tried to update android studio from stable channel to canary and cleaning the project. Nothing was working except this solution.