# pod install in cocoapods not working after updating macOS to catalina

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, macos-catalina

When executing `$pod install` at specific xcode workspace folder,

the terminal shows:

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`
```

... `usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`...

cannot update any of the pods listed in the podfile list. Is this related to cocoapods problem?

Comment: just run this in your terminal: 

    sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442214/running-pod-set-up-gives-me-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Bash has been replaced by zsh as the new Mac OS shell. just run the supplied line `chsh -s /bin/zsh`

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused by the system update of macOS. You need to update your *cocoapods* after updating your macOS system from the terminal.

You can **update** your *cocoapods* by executing the following command lines:

```
$ sudo gem update --system
$ sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin
```

This works for me (**macOS** Catalina 10.15)

Comment: Try this "gem install mygem --user-install"