# Terminal installation of CooaPods

Tags: terminal, cocoapods, podfile

Here's my terminal export:

Here for pod init:

```
Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ ls
GoodDays        GoodDaysTests
GoodDays.xcodeproj  GoodDaysUITests

Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ pod init
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Here for cocoapods install:

```
Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210114-6600-1nfobc.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.14.2/gem_make.out
```

A final note. I tried to update RubyGems:

```
Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I have also tried this:

```
Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin
Successfully installed nanaimo-0.3.0
Successfully installed colored2-3.1.2
Successfully installed claide-1.0.3
Successfully installed atomos-0.1.3
Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.19.0
Successfully installed ruby-macho-1.4.0
Successfully installed molinillo-0.6.6
Successfully installed gh_inspector-1.1.3
Successfully installed fourflusher-2.3.1
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.5.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.4
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210114-6782-1lu9tjk.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.14.2/gem_make.out
Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ ls
GoodDays        GoodDaysTests
GoodDays.xcodeproj  GoodDaysUITests
Masons-iMac:GoodDays nacly$ pod init
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "nacly" shouldn't be an issue, all after the "$" should be the "real command", so it's okay. Install again CocoaPods ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442214/running-pod-set-up-gives-me-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory